# How to get PPID with 'ps aux' under AIX?

Tags: aix, ps

I know it is possible with `ps -ef` but I want to get it with the command: `ps aux`

How to do it on `AIX`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ps aux is the berkley standard of ps.

```
ps [ a ] [ c ] [ e ] [ ew ] [ eww ] [ ewww ] [ g ] [ n ] [ w ] [ x ] [ l | s | u | v ] [ t tty ] [ X ] [ ProcessNumber ]

a = Displays information about all processes with terminals (ordinarily only the own processes of the user are displayed).
u = Displays user-oriented output. This includes the USER, PID, %CPU, %MEM, SZ, RSS, TTY, STAT, STIME, TIME, and COMMAND fields.
x = Displays processes without a controlling terminal in addition to processes with a controlling terminal.
```

as you can see in the command flags, you can only use one of these: "[ l | s | u | v ]"

```
l = Displays a long listing having the F, S, UID, PID, PPID, C, PRI, NI, ADDR, SZ, PSS, WCHAN, TTY, TIME, and CMD fields.
s = Displays the size (SSIZ) of the kernel stack of each process (for use by system maintainers) in the basic output format. This value is always 0 (zero) for a multi-threaded process.
u = Displays user-oriented output. This includes the USER, PID, %CPU, %MEM, SZ, RSS, TTY, STAT, STIME, TIME, and COMMAND fields.
v = Displays the PGIN, SIZE, RSS, LIM, TSIZ, TRS, %CPU, %MEM fields.
```

You can replace the 'u' with the 'l', although you won't have all the fields you will have in the 'u'.

you can also use the X/Open variant:

```
ps -ef -o "ruser pid ppid pcpu pmem vsz rssize tty stat start time command"
```

you can also change -e to -A if you want all processes. -e doesn't give you kernel processes, -A does.

```
-e Writes information to standard output about all processes, except kernel processes.
-A Writes to standard output information about all processes.
```

Comment: should be `ps -e -o "uid pid ppid pcpu pmem vsz rssize tty stat start time command"`  , remove the option `-f`